# How to change V$SESSION values in Oracle Database using Golang

Tags: oracle, go

I tried to find the way to set in the connection to Oracle with golang all the parameters of v$session, has anyone an example of that?

```
V$session.machine
V$session.osuser
V$session.process
V$session.terminal
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible.  By design the Oracle C API (used by the godror driver and others) doesn't let these be faked.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, you now if there are other option to set that?

Comment: Why do you want to fake them?  That doesn't help auditing.

Comment: the reason is to authenticate by host machine that makes the connection to the database, all this is in openshift to identify the pod, and the access is with the pod, there are a better form?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/175? If you do real authentication by a value that can be changed, it doesn't sound secure.  Perhaps you mean something else?  I'd look at a wallet based authentication mechanism.

Comment: Hi! I was reading so I found this. ContextWithTraceTag with that I can send the info what we want, but There is a way to use it when creating the connection and not only when we generate a query?

Comment: Use a dedicated service name and check SERVICE_NAME in V$SESSION?